# Laptop disconnects from WiFi Randomly, repeatedly fixed by Repair option in Windows XP Pro

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-xp, connection

How can keep it from disconnecting? The Repair option always fixes it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the Power Saving Mode to Constantly Awake Mode (CAM) or Disabled and see whether it makes a difference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I changed it and now going to give u a +1 if the problem is fixed. Thanks.

Comment: you're more than welcome.

Comment: /foreheadSlap! I bet that's going to solve a problem that I've been ignoring for months... thanks for the clue-by-four :-)